# Resolution Time - VBA? Formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to calculate resolution times in excel based off of a data pull from HP ALM QC.

We have separate statuses for time spent with QA, Dev, and Business. I want to produce a report showing the resolution time for each item using their Defect ID, by department.

Resolution time recording hours (24 hours a day):-

```
Start:     10:00 PM PST Sunday
End:       5:00 PM PST Friday
```

Statuses:

```
New (Starting point)
Open - Dev
Open - QA
Open - Bus
Open - Admin
Fixed (Stops Clock)
Failed (Starts Clock against Dev)
Closed (Stops Clock)
Cancelled (Stops Clock)
```

These are the columns from the data pull:

```
ID# 
TIMSESTAMP  
STATUS  
VERSION 
LEAD    
SEVERITY    
CAUSE       
PARENT  
FAILS   
COMPANY
```

I would also like to conditionally format the report to highlight any resolution times in red that exceed these goals:

Resolution Time SLAs:

```
A: 8 hours
B: 24 hours
C: 32 hours
D: 48 hours
E: 72 hours
F: 72 hours
```

I don't know where to start. We were using VBA for the way we used to calculate resolution time, but the error rate was over 20%. I'm very new to this, so I apologize if I am leaving anything out.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data, how you define resolution time and anything you have attempted thus far? It may be best to [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) then restate your question.

Comment: @kyle Unfortunately I cannot upload a file to a hosting site on my work  PC, but this is a sample. Sorry for the format... ID# TIMSESTAMP STATUS VERSION LEAD SEVERITY CAUSE PARENT FAILS COMPANY
201701716 3/29/2017 0:15 OPEN - DEV 5 CENSORED C 3 698248 0 CCC
201701716 3/29/2017 9:38 OPEN - QA 5 CENSORED C 3 698248 0 CCC
201701716 3/31/2017 18:02 OPEN - DEV 5 CENSORED C 3 698248 0 CCC
201701716 4/3/2017 5:40 Fixed 5 CENSORED C 3 698248 0 CCC
201701716 4/5/2017 0:07 Closed 5 CENSORED C 3 698248 0 CCC

Comment: **Edit your question to include your sample**.  Then you can create a readable example.

Comment: Select *EDIT** and paste it in as code. If it looks rough, someone will fix it.

Comment: @Ron Rosendeld I was able to upload a file in another forum [link](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/180535-Time-Spent-in-Each-Status-Calculation?p=1086126#post1086126)

Comment: @Kyle I was able to upload to another forum  [link](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/180535-Time-Spent-in-Each-Status-Calculation?p=1086126#post1086126)

Comment: Had you done what I requested, I might be able to review it. But I'm not joining another forum just to download your file.  I also don't see any sign of the code you've been using. In addition to the tour recommended by @Kyle, I suggest you also read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks anyway @RonRosenfeld, I was unable to submit the data formatted here. The HTML does not accept table formatting, I only was able to produce the same result as in my comment. I did not realize you had to join the other forum to download, it seems to download fine for me without logging in.

Answer (score 0):

This was much easier to figure out than I thought.

This can be done with a formula and a pivot table.

The data must be in order from oldest timestamp to newest, then sorted by the item ID #.

You subtract the newer timestamp from the older, and apply MAX(0 to the formula to prevent negative numbers appearing when switching defects.

Then pivot the data for totals.